# Issue with CSV Import Script Failing to Finish towards the end | PHP

Tags: php, csv

I currently have the following PHP script that allows me to select and upload a CSV file and then importing all of the rows into a mySQL table with the same structure.

In my case I have script with 12,974 rows that need to be imported into the table but it always only gets to 12,895 before reloading the page and stopping the import.

The following is the code so far:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
{
    //First we need to make a connection with the database
    $host='localhost'; // Host Name.
    $db_user= 'dbuser'; //User Name
    $db_password= '';
    $db= 'dbname'; // Database Name.
    $conn=mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password) or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db) or die (mysql_error());
    echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
    {

        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        $count = 0;
        while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
            //print_r($emapData);
            //exit();
            $count++;

        if($count>1){
        $sql = "INSERT into Table1(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7, Column8, Column9, Column10) values ('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]','$emapData[4]','$emapData[5]','$emapData[6]','$emapData[7]','$emapData[8]','$emapData[9]')";
        mysql_query($sql);
            }
        }
        fclose($file);
        echo 'CSV File has been successfully Imported';
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    else
        echo 'Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File';
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">File Upload</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="150">
        <p class="help-block">Only Excel/CSV File Import.</p>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Import" value="Import">Upload</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Switch your code to use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead. Be sure to use prepared statements and parameter binding, so **you'll never have to worry about quoting issues again.**

Comment: You may need to raise the timeout if the process is taking longer than 30 seconds.

Comment: If there aren't all of the columns on that line, then the insert will fail.  Perhaps worth checking the file for missing values (or just report and ignore the line).

Comment: Yes it about 10-15 minutes to upload 12,000+ records, but it doesn’t “timeout” until there’s about 200 left (15 minutes later) which makes me doubt its a time issue

Comment: If it takes 10-15 minutes to upload, then the browser is probably closing the connection. Most browsers close the connection after 5 minutes. You may want to offload the actual import process to a command-line script

Comment: How can this be done? I appreciate your help

Comment: One thing I often do for cases like this is have the initial upload request save the file to the server, makes a request to another action (in MVC-speak) with an instant timeout and ignore_user_abort set, and then just return a response to the user that the file is being processed and they will be emailed when it is complete (obviously you'd need to collect email when the file is uploaded to do that).  The request to the "other action" is what actually inserts the data into the database.  The user then isn't left just watching the screen

Comment: @PatrickQ Can you please show how something like this can be done? Right now the file is being uploaded into a temp directory

Comment: @JohnRetson  I've laid out enough for you to get started down that path.  You just break up your logic into two requests.

Answer (score 0):

Set following attributes in php.ini file

upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 21M

And at begining of script set following also
ini_set('max_execution_time', '300'); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0'); /